# If the events $\{E_n\}$ satisfy a certain property show that $P(\cap_{i=1}^k E_i) > 0$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let  $\{E_n\}$ be events such that $\sum_{i=1}^kP(E_i) > k - 1$ then we want to show that  $P(\cap_{i=1}^k E_i) > 0$.

My approach for this problem is by contradiction. Suppose $P(\cap_{i=1}^k E_i) = 0$ and then try and arrive at a contradiction. Since $P(E_i) \in [0,1]$ then we know there is no event such that $P(E_i) = 0$ or otherwise $\sum_{i=1}^kP(E_i) \le k - 1$.  But we are not told if the events are  independent. I am not sure how from knowing $P(\cap_{i=1}^k E_i) = 0$ to go to making conclusions about  $\sum_{i=1}^kP(E_i)$.

Comment: Note that for $k = 2$, you have $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) > (2-1) - 1 = 0.$ Do you know inclusion-exclusion? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability Can you generalise?

Comment: Ohh, i didn't think of doing that, thanks let me try it.

Comment: @snarski I understand why we need to use the general version of the inclusion-exclusion principle here. But would the approach still be by contradiction, or a more algebraic computational approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think you can do it using inclusion-exclusion. I don't know if this is ''direct'', I'm sure you can make it so.

Note that $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$
\begin{align*}
P(\cap_{i=1}^n E_i) &= 1 - P(\cup_{i=1}^n E_i^c) \\
&\geq 1 - \sum_{i=1}^nP(E_i^c) \tag{subtracting more}
\end{align*}
so it suffices to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n P(E_i^c) < 1$, since then we can conclude the right hand side of the inequality is $> 0$. However this follows immediately from the condition:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n P(E_i) &> n - 1 \\
\iff\;\; \sum_{i=1}^n (1-P(E_i^c)) &> n -1 \\
\iff\;\; n - \sum_{i=1}^n P(E_i^c) &> n -1 \\
\iff\;\; 1 &> \sum_{i=1}^n P(E_i^c)
\end{align*}
Now you just need to polish it out into a clean thought.